# reading a file into an array ... I dont understand where the error is coming from

Tags: java, arrays

//reads file into a String array

```
public String[] readFixedString()throws FileNotFoundException
 {
  int i = 0;
  Scanner fileIn=null;
  try
  {
    fileIn = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("Spices.txt"));
  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   System.exit(0);
  }
  while(fileIn.hasNextLine())
  {
   this.textfile[i++] = fileIn.nextLine();
  }

  fileIn.close();
  return textfile;

 }
```

**main method**

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException
   {
  ProductData pd=new ProductData();

  pd.readFixedString();
   }
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at ProductData.readFixedString(ProductData.java:57)
>         at ProductData.main(ProductData.java:125)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at u.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)

I Don't understand where my error is coming from my file does exist and the path is being followed to the right spot i checked by just reading in the file with out putting the entries into an array

Comment: where did you declared textfile?

Comment: When you fixed this, you will run into out of bounds using that array. Except you make it really big... better use some List implementation. For example ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

`this.textfile` is most likely `null`, ensure you initialise it properly:

```
this.textfile = new String[your_size];
```

Or, as suggested, rather use a `List` implementation such as `ArrayList`:

```
private final List<String> textFile = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: i think he should use an ArrayList or something, because the OP won't be knowing the size of the String array to initialize

Comment: @SarthakMittal, definitely! just pointing out the problem here :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
{
        File f=new File("test.txt");
        LineNumberReader lineReader=new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(f));
        int counter=0;
        while(lineReader.ready())
        {
            lineReader.readLine();
        }
        lineReader.close();
        counter=lineReader.getLineNumber();
        System.out.println(counter);
        String [] str=new String[counter];
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(f);
        int i=0;
        while(scan.hasNextLine())
        {
            str[i++]=scan.nextLine();
        }
        scan.close();
        for (String string : str)
        {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this since you say you have a problem with your file, also make sure your 
file path is correct. This is an implementation using ArrayList

```
  ArrayList<String> textFile = new ArrayList<String>();
  File file = new File("Spices.txt"); 
  Scanner fileIn =  new Scanner(file); 
  while(fileIn.hasNextLine()){
     textFile.add(fileIn.nextLine());
  }
  fileIn.close();
```